# Why Intellij IDEA 15.0.3 does not generate Foreign Keys, while adding Hibernate Framework support?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, intellij-idea

I have mysql database with 3 tables in it:
books - contains unique id;
reviews - has foreign key, related to books;
sales  - has foreign key, related to books.

Mysql Workbench shows the relation of 3 tables correctly:

[Relations in Mysql Reverse Engineer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJJ1d.png)

However, when i am creating new hibernate project in Intellij, it does not recognize the foreign keys and does not implement them in code:

[New Hibernate project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EzXB.png)

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSKlo.png)

*(Note: including book_id checkboxes also does not help)*

After generation of project there are no attributes for corresponding foreign keys in classes "SalesEntity and "ReviewsEntity":

[Sales table mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9teY.png)

[Reviews table mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhdGu.png)

Generated hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mikodb</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <mapping class="com.BooksEntity"/>
        <mapping class="com.ReviewsEntity"/>
        <mapping class="com.SalesEntity"/>
        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The same situation appears when i am trying to add Hibernate framework support to existing project.
What could be the reason, that foreign keys are lost during database mapping?

Comment: Tried the same project on another PC. In Intellij 2018.1 situation is same.

Comment: So you should not tag with intellij-15. You should tag with specific versions only when the specific version is relevant :)

Comment: Ok, i've changed the tag.

Comment: There is similar issue reported on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113600

Comment: We had to use NetBean for Entity creation

Comment: So this is a bug of IDEA? And it exists already 5 years... Ok, thanks for info. I will use NetBeans for Entity creation.